# Conceal passwords in configuration files but maintain password length

Tags: syntax-highlighting, conceal

## Preamble

I often share my screen with other developers over discord. When I navigate to a `.env` file that has sensitive information, I'd like to conceal that information while still allowing others to see the context.

Example file:

```
DATABASE_URL="postgresql://dummy:dummy@172.20.0.3:5432/dummy"
HEDERA_TOPIC_ID=0.0.1624219
INFURA_API_KEY=somesecretkeyidrathernotshare
KMS_SECRET_KEY=
WALLET_PRIVATE_KEY=
```

Desired result:

```
DATABASE_URL="postgresql://dummy:dummy@172.20.0.3:5432/dummy"
HEDERA_TOPIC_ID=0.0.1624219
INFURA_API_KEY=*****************************
KMS_SECRET_KEY=
WALLET_PRIVATE_KEY=
```

I first searched for a plugin that does exactly this, but I couldn't find anything suitable.

## Attempts

### First Attempt

```
:syn match Secrets /^.*KEY=.*$/ conceal cchar=*
:setl cole=2 cocu=nvc
```

Which looks like this:

```bash
*
```

**All context is lost.**

### Second Attempt

```
:syn match Secrets /\(^.*KEY=\)\@<=.*$/ conceal cchar=*
:setl cole=2 cocu=nvc
```

Which produces:

```bash
INFURA_API_KEY=*
```

**Better, but it's not that easy to see and doesn't look nice.**

Comment: Frame challenge: You should not store passwords or other sensitive information in config files. You should use a key management infrastructure that provides passwords during runtime.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would recommend to use [matchadd()](https://vimhelp.org/builtin.txt.html#matchadd%28%29) function for this, because it is independent of syntax highlighting and a bit more flexible.

For your particular use case, the following should work:

```
call matchadd('Conceal', '\(KEY=.*\)\@<=.', 10, -1, {'conceal': '*'})
```

The key here is to use `\@<=` regex atom that matches for each character after the `KEY=.` followed by any character, so it can replace each password character by a simple `*`.

In addition you need to have the following settings, to make sure concealing works as you expect:

```
:set conceallevel=2 concealcursor=nv
```

This will make sure to use the *conceal character* instead of highlighting simply the match and will keep it concealed in normal and visual mode, even if the cursor is on the line which contains your password.

See the documentation for those options here: ['conceallevel'](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27conceallevel%27), ['concealcursor'](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27concealcursor%27)

Related answer from a few years ago: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34544986/789222

Comment: I find this doesn't work if the screen is split. The current active window takes the conceal, leaving the original unprotected. Is there a way for this to apply to every window at the same time?

Comment: matches are window-local. So you need to combine this with a WinEnter/BufWinEnter autocommand

Answer (score 5):

## Working solution 1

```
:syn match SecretKeys /\(^.*_KEY=\)\@<=.*$/ contains=SecretKeyChars
:syn match SecretKeyChars /.\ze\_./ conceal contained cchar=*
:setl cole=2 cocu=nvc
```

The `SecretKeys` group defines the context of the match, i.e. the region where the other group `SecretKeyChars` will operate.

`SecretKeyChars` matches anything, but one at a time `\ze`. The final `\_.` means that the singular match against anything will work if the next character is "anything" or an eol (without this the last character is still visible).

`cole` is `conceallevel` and 2 allows the `cchar` to be visible.
`cocu` is `concealcursor` and defines the modes when the conceal will be active, in this case `nvc`: normal, visual, and command line editing. This means that the password will be visible if I try to edit the line.

Lua config:

```lua
-- Conceal paswords and secrets
local conceal_secrets_group = vim.api.nvim_create_augroup("ConcealSecretsGroup", {})
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd({ "BufEnter" }, {
    group = conceal_secrets_group,
    callback = function()
        vim.cmd.syntax([[match SecretKeyChars /.\ze\_./ conceal contained cchar=*]])
        vim.cmd.syntax([[match SecretKeys /\(^.*_KEY=\)\@<=.*$/ contains=SecretKeyChars]])
    end,
})
vim.opt.conceallevel = 2
vim.opt.concealcursor = "nvc"
```

This triggers everytime a buffer is entered. To extend, copy-paste the `vim.cmd.syntax` lines, change the match names (`SecretKeys`, `SecretKeyChars`) and match pattern (`^.*_KEY=`)

## Working Solution 2

Uses matchadd solution described by [@christian](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/71/christian-brabandt)

Lua config:

```lua
-- Conceal paswords and secrets
local conceal_secrets_group = vim.api.nvim_create_augroup("ConcealSecretsGroup", {})
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd({ "WinEnter", "BufWinEnter" }, {
    group = conceal_secrets_group,
    callback = function()
        vim.fn.matchadd('Conceal', '\\(KEY=.*\\)\\@<=.', 10, -1, {conceal = '*'})
    end,
})
vim.opt.conceallevel = 2
vim.opt.concealcursor = "nv"
```